# SAP JCo 3.x Linux 64bit Download

Tags: download, jco

is there any possibility to get the SAP JCo 3.x Linux 64bit library except from SAP Marketplace?

Thanks
zwaem

Comment: Not a legal one, and asking for download links is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : No

Long answer : No, SAP does not provide the JCo toolkits as freeware or open source. These are licensed SAP products and are only made available to SAP customers. You will need to have a logon to the SAP Service Marketplace, which is only available to customers of SAP.